# CSS - Force overflowing elements to disappear if partially hidden

Tags: css

Let's say we have a box with some short paragraphs:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

The height of the box is variable, so sometimes one of the paragraphs' text is partially hidden.

Is there a CSS property that would force the paragraph to either display fully or not at all, or would this need to be calculated using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know no way to do this with CSS but with JavaScript, you can check:

```
var parent = element.parentElement;
if (element.clientTop + element.clientHeight > parent.clientTop + parent.clientHeight) {
    ... element is outside parent ...
}
```

You can use a binary search to find the last completely visible paragraph.

Comment: the year 2021: this JS solution still stays one of the best ones for wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage, and its inherited tools! display: flex;flex-flow: column wrap;overflow: hidden; should be supported and better there but ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comment from PIoneer_2, it's possible to achieve this with CSS flexbox wrapping.

In the following example, `.wrapper` has a fixed width and height and `.child` has a fixed height. Because all `.child` elements can't fit on one flex row, the last `.child` is pushed down to the next row. However, the next row is hidden, because we use `overflow: hidden`, so the result is that the partially overflowing element is completely hidden.

```html
<style>
.wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 1em;
  width: 120px;
}
.child {
  align-items: center;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
.child + .child {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">Lorem</div>
  <div class="child">Ipsum</div>
  <div class="child">Dolor</div>
</div>
```