# Is there a CSS only way to completely hide elements that partially overflow?

Tags: css

Imagine you have an element that has a height that is a percentage of the browser window height. This element contains a bunch of block elements.

Is there a way to use something like `overflow: hidden` but make sure that the last block element is completely hidden instead of partially hidden if it overflows?

(This is pretty easy to do with JavaScript, but I'd prefer to solve this with the stylesheet.)

Comment: Could you write an example with the problem in jsfiddle or something? Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to do that. What you may try is to have the first element that doesn't fit fully be pushed out of view, but whether that is possible or not depends on the layout in question.

Comment: Apart from the container having a height that is exactly a multiple of the height of each of its children, I don't think so

Comment: There is no CSS only way, although there is a simple JS solution to that. But since you've asked for CSS only, the answer is no.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It wasn't possible in 2013, but now all IE<=10 are dead, we can use flexbox.

The basic idea is to wrap flex items out of visible area.

Remove `overflow: hidden;` to see where the items go.

```js
$('.parent').ready(function() {
  $('.parent').resizable();
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  height:288px;
  width: 233px;
  border: 5px dashed blue;
  background: yellow;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
<div class="child">0</div>
<div class="child">1</div>
<div class="child">2</div>
<div class="child">3</div>
<div class="child">4</div>
<div class="child">5</div>
<div class="child">6</div>
<div class="child">7</div>
<div class="child">8</div>
<div class="child">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to achieve the same effect but horizontally? I've got a slider in which I want to hide partially visible slides.

Comment: if CSS is not an option - check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583281/6344916

Answer (score 0):

Alright, there is essentially no way in which you can do this with pure CSS, unless you happen to be developing only for earlier internet explorer versions (use of expression()).

Basically, it's no longer possible to run javascript within a style sheet (which was really your only option of doing this all on the style sheet).

It's not that difficult to do in Jquery though:
http://jsfiddle.net/bernie1227/wCx9N/

This solution basically just utilises:

```
pageWidth - (elementWidth + elementLeft) < 0
```

In order to check if the element is overflowing.