# Completely hiding block elements that don't fully fit in the visible part of their parent

Tags: css

Suppose I have three block elements in a container.  The black line indicates the container.  The blue boxes are the three block elements within it.

[image: Elements]

These three elements don't quite fit.  If I set `overflow: hidden` on the outer element, I will see the top two elements and partially the third.

What I would like, is to only display elements that fully fit within the container.

[image: Elements, corrected]

Is this possible with CSS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible with `Flexbox`, you need to set `flex-direction: column` , `flex-wrap: wrap` and also `overflow: hidden`.

Also you need to set full width or `calc(100% - margin)` on flex-childs so when last elements wraps itself it will go out of parent element and `overflow: hidden`  on parent will take care of rest.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 70px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background: #46A1FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably here the properties are separated for clarity purposes, but people tend to forget `flex-flow` can be used as a shorthand property for `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap`. `flex-flow: column wrap;`

Comment: if CSS is not an option - check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583281/6344916