# Hide partially overflown elements

Tags: css

I am looking for a pure CSS approach to hide div 3 that has partially overflown its container. See the attached image.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with your markup and the specific css?

Comment: You want to hide the whole div with css when it overflows? If yes, this is not possible with css only.

Comment: @Huelfe It is. And tricky ;) Not as tricky as [multiline ellipsis](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/) though (that was the last time I said something isn't possible in CSS ^^)

Comment: a straight JS solution works here also - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583281/6344916

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working solution that'll entirely hide an item that wouldn't fit in the fixed height of its parent: **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/JyBQOy?editors=0100)**

It uses Multi-Column Layout in a tricky way with :pseudos and `overflow: hidden` as a final touch. OK on Fx, Chrome, Edge and IE11 (if you don't use Custom Properties as I did for a better understanding. Preprocessor variables will be fine)

- `.container` has a fixed height otherwise the question makes no sense
- Same `.container` is twice as large as expected. It has 2 columns with no gap/gutter
- Its :pseudo `:after` exists (the translucid tomato blob) and thus is considered as a 4th item to be taken into account in this 2-columns layout. Its height is 100% => it makes the 3rd item occupy the 2nd column if it doesn't have enough room on 1st column (2nd example)
- Parent `.mask` has the width we want (half of `.container`) and `overflow: hidden`: the 2nd column of `.container` is clipped. You can remove latter declaration to see what it clips
- …
- Profit!

```css
:root {
  --w: 40rem;
  --p-horiz: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.mask {
  width: calc(var(--w));
  overflow: hidden; /* REMOVE to see the trick */
  /*padding: 0 1rem; NOPE */
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background-color: #aaa;
  /*outline: 1px dashed red;*/
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: column;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 0;
  width: calc(var(--w) * 2);
  /*max-*/height: 25rem; /* max-height also work, at least on Fx */
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FF634780;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

/* 1. Sufficient for Fx */
/* 2. Needed for Chrome */
[class^="item-"] {
  overflow: hidden; /* 1. */
  display: inline-block; /* 2. */
  width: calc(100% - 2 * var(--p-horiz)); /* 2. */
  margin-left: var(--p-horiz);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ddd;
  /*outline: 1px dashed blue;*/
}

.item-1 {
  height: 8rem;
}

.item-2 {
  height: 4rem;
}

.item-3 {
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.alt .item-3 {
  height: 16rem;
}

.mask:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

[class^="item-"]:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item-1">Block 1</div>
    <div class="item-2">Block 2</div>
    <div class="item-3">Block 3</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="mask">
  <div class="container alt">
    <div class="item-1">Block 1</div>
    <div class="item-2">Block 2</div>
    <div class="item-3">Block 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this works if you have a really big image as one of your elements. It will just crop the image, which I don't think is the desired behavior.

Comment: Basically, if you div size is larger than the size of your column, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Our team looked for solution on hiding vertically content which overflows

But, simple `overflow: hidden` wouldn't work because it can hide overflowing content partially.

And we wanted to hide it fully.

So, @FelipeAls suggested to use css columns

And yes, it actually works

**VIDEO DEMO**: https://streamable.com/3tdc8

**JSBIN**: http://jsbin.com/fumiquhoxo/2/edit?html,css,output

Launchable example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #container {
        padding: 5px;
        height: 50px;
        resize: both;
        
        /*
        Change this to "visible" to see how it works
        */
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #container-2 {
        height: 100%;
        width: 200%;
        column-count: 2;
        column-fill: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 150px; outline: 1px red solid;">
    <div id="container-2">
        <div>ONE LINE</div>
        <div>SECOND LINE</div>
        <div>THIRD LINE</div>
        <div>FOURTH LINE</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this works if you have a really big image as one of your elements. It will just crop the image, which I don't think is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. In case If you want to hide it, use property `overflow: hidden`

```css
.container {
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: auto;
}
.el {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el">Div 1</div>
  <div class="el">Div 2</div>
  <div class="el">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or you want to hide the whole `div`?

Comment: Yes, hide the whole div

Comment: You may need to use jQuery or JavaScript to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: gray;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">div 1</div>
  <div class="box">div 2</div>
  <div class="box">div 3</div>
</div>
```