# Odd layout behaviour with css columns wrapping overflowing elements in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide half-overflowed items in my CSS. I found a great method using css columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48378030/1305699

It works great in Firefox, but in Chrome I found some really odd behaviour under certain seemingly random combinations. For example, I managed to re-produce it by adding a height to one of the items, when the container is certain specific sizes, it causes the layout to randomly flicker into very odd sizes.

This is it working fine:

[image]

But sometimes when the last item, with a `height: 20px` style, it randomly looks like this:

[image]

In some positions, chrome even thinks it's rendering it correctly in the (hidden) second column, but it's actually being drawn half off, and at an odd size, in the first column:

[image]

Has anyone seen this issue and know a solution or workaround?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  resize: both;

  overflow: hidden;
}

#container-2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
}

.item {
  background: aliceblue;
  margin: 2px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item div {
   margin: 0.3rem;
}

.item span {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" style="width: 150px; outline: 1px red solid;">
    <div id="container-2">
      <div class="item">ONE LINE</div>
      <div class="item">
        <div>i</div><span>SECOND LINE</span>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div>i</div><span>THIRD LINE</span>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div>i</div><span style="height: 20px;">FOURTH LINE</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, turns out I need the `break-inside: avoid` on the items which makes the column avoid attempting to break items over the column.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/